# How to force clear user's browser all the time?

Tags: browser, cache-control, no-cache

We're working on a website. Our client want to check the website daily, but they're facing a problem. Whenever we make a change on the website, they have to clear their browser cache.

So I added the following header to my server configuration

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

As far as I see, firefox is receiving this header and I'm pretty sure that it is obeying it.

My question is, is this "Cache-Control: no-cache" guaranteed and does it work across all the browsers (including IEs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it's handy to use a "useless" version number in the requests. For example, instead of requesting `script.js`, request `script.js?v=1.0`

If you are generating your pages dynamically (PHP, etc) you can just keep the version number in a variable and only have to update it in one place whenever you update. If you want the content *never* to be cached, just use the output of `time()` as your version number.

**EDIT:** have you tried asking your client to change his browser caching settings? That way you can bypass the problem entirely

Comment: // thank you for the suggestions, but...I like to know if it is possible to force user's browser not to cache anything only with the header.